# Remove array items based on sub array duplicate values and then sort in custom order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, duplicates, filtering

Remove array items based on duplicate values that appear 1 level deeper inside the array. Once the items have been sorted of duplicates, then would be cool to re order the new array.

This is the current input array...

```
$downloads = [
    ['type' => 'PHOTOS'],
    ['type' => 'DOCUMENTS'],
    ['type' => 'DOCUMENTS'],
    ['type' => 'VIDEOS'],
    ['type' => 'PHOTOS'],
];
```

I would like to remove all duplicates from this input so I am left with this new output...

```
[
    ['type' => 'PHOTOS'],
    ['type' => 'DOCUMENTS'],
    ['type' => 'VIDEOS'],
]
```

But is it possible to set and ordering to each `TYPE` value. For example can I set predetermined orders using a variables or something. Any advice on re-ordering the new array to a specific order. Using this new order...

```
$photos = 1;
$videos = 2;
$documents = 3;
```

or a new order using an array maybe...

```
$new_order = array(
  1 => 'PHOTOS',
  2 => 'VIDEOS',
  3 => 'DOCUMENTS'
)
```

---

Any help would be so good. I've tried [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) and array_map but I can't seem to find out how to specify which sub array key to check for duplicates.

This is what i've tried so far...

```
$downloads = get_field('downloads');
$types = array_unique($downloads));
```

and

```
$downloads = get_field('downloads');
$types = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $downloads)));
```

I didn't get as far as re ordering the array.

Comment: I'm not sure what re-ordering technique you're saying about. But you can use `array_unique` to remove those duplicates.

Comment: `array_unique` wouldn't work on multidimensional arrays

Comment: Can you, please, clear something out. Do you want to only get an array of unique types or the array of input items with unique types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `array_column`, `array_map`, `array_search` and `usort` functions:

```
$new_order = array(
  0 => 'PHOTOS',
  1 => 'VIDEOS',
  2 => 'DOCUMENTS'
);

// $downloads is your input array
$types = array_map(function ($v) {
    return ['TYPE' => $v];
},array_unique(array_column($downloads, 'TYPE')));

usort($types, function($a, $b) use($new_order){
    $a_key = array_search($a['TYPE'], $new_order);
    $b_key = array_search($b['TYPE'], $new_order);

    if ($a_key == $b_key) return 0;
    return ($a_key < $b_key)? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($types);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TYPE] => PHOTOS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [TYPE] => VIDEOS
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [TYPE] => DOCUMENTS
        )
)
```

Comment: I've just tested this here http://phpio.net/s/1lql and it works great too. Thank you for you time. So which do you think works faster, [your answer](http://phpio.net/s/1lql) or [piotr's answer](http://phpio.net/s/1lpr). @piotr's answer is less code than yours.

Comment: @joshmoto, you forgot one thing - in @piotr's answer the resulting array doesn't have `TYPE` keys, as they appeared in the initial array

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty solution for removing "subarray" duplicates:

```
$a = [];
$a[]['type'] = 'photos';
$a[]['type'] = 'documents';
$a[]['type'] = 'documents';
$a[]['type'] = 'videos';
$a[]['type'] = 'photos';


$b = [];
foreach( $a as $index => $subA ) {
   if( in_array($subA['type'], $b) ) {
        unset($a[$index]);
   } else {
       $b[] = $subA['type'];
   }
}
```

Regarding the sorting: Just set the indices with the order you need them and after removing the duplicates use ksort (assuming I did understand you right).

Comment: Quick and dirty maybe but it removes all duplicates just fine :-) http://phpio.net/s/1lpi thank you for time but i'm guna give it to @piotr cuase his function is what i'm after. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) that computes common part of two arrays. If you use order array as first argument, order of that will be preserved.

Your input:

```
$input = [
    ['TYPE' => 'PHOTOS'],
    ['TYPE' => 'DOCUMENTS'],
    ['TYPE' => 'DOCUMENTS'],
    ['TYPE' => 'VIDEOS'],
    ['TYPE' => 'PHOTOS']
];
```

I've write simple function to achieve all of your needs:

```
function do_awesomness($input, $key = 'TYPE', $order = ['PHOTOS', 'VIDEOS', 'DOCUMENTS'])
{
    $result = [];
    foreach($input as $k => $value)
        $result[] = $value[$key];
    $result = array_unique($result);

    return array_values(array_intersect($order, $result));
}
```

Usage:

```
do_awesomness($input);
```

Working example: http://phpio.net/s/1lo1

Comment: This does look like awesomness to me but I had a play on phpio.nets with the actually array that i'm trying to filter and it's trowing an error. Is it because your example array is only one level deep? Please see your working example modified using my multidimensional array input http://phpio.net/s/1lpl

Comment: Everything is working fine. Just change `TYPE` to `type`, and order values to `Photos`, `Videos` and `Documents`

Comment: This will only return an array of unique types, not the array of unique input items. Also, you can drop `foreach` and use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Comment: No. @joshmoto wanted to get TYPE index returned. My function allows him to return any other index.

Comment: Actually you're right, i've just updated the case sensitive values here http://phpio.net/s/1lpr and its giving me the perfect output. Thank @piotr for you solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to reimplement [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), but collecting unique types in order of appearance. This will help us to sort array later.

```
$order = [
    'PHOTOS' => 1,
    'VIDEOS' => 2,
    'DOCUMENTS' => 3    
];

$types = [];
$uniqueDownloads = array_reduce(
    $downloads,
    function ($uniqueDownloads, $download) use (&$types, $order) {
        $type = $download['TYPE'];

        if (!isset($types[$type])) {
            $types[$type] = isset($order[$type]) ? $order[$type] : 0;
            $uniqueDownloads[] = $download;   
        }

        return $uniqueDownloads;
    },
    []
);

array_multisort($types, $uniqueDownloads);
```

Traversing the array we check whether the type key exists in `$types`. If it exists skip this element. Otherwise, set this key and assign value from `$order` to it (this will be used for sorting).

We then use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to sort `$uniqueDownloads` by sorting `$types`.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6472123508391634b7c0e224baabcb0627b9fc5).

Read more about [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). I have passed `$types` by reference with `&` so the function change value of the original array, but not the value of the copy.

Comment: Thank you for your help, though another guy answered and the he too used wasnt the same array that I think I have. Though I may be wrong and I will test now in my live envirnment with both solutions. But i've updated your working demo here with my array input instead. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fee5fe1a10a3505803714bf4de82df7aa2482645 thanks

Comment: @joshmoto, the problem with `TYPE` and `type` keys. You can change the case and it will work.

Comment: I've had a play with your version.. see fiddle http://phpio.net/s/1lq5, based on the same array i've used in fiddles on other answers, i'm sure its probably a mistake i've made, but i'm probably guna give the question to @piotr and his function does what i need. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @joshmoto, in the fiddle, it makes sense to add `var_dump($uniqueDownloads);` to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

For custom ordering I recommended `usort`:

```
$array = [
    ['TYPE'=>'PHOTOS'],
    ['TYPE'=>'DOCUMENTS'],
    ['TYPE'=>'VIDEOS']
    ];

function customOrder($a, $b){
    $newOrder = [
      'PHOTOS' => 1,
      'VIDEOS' => 2,
      'DOCUMENTS' => 3
    ];

    $valA = (array_key_exists($a['TYPE'],$newOrder))?$newOrder[$a['TYPE']]:999;
    $valB = (array_key_exists($b['TYPE'],$newOrder))?$newOrder[$b['TYPE']]:999;

    if($valA > $valB){
        $result = 1;
    } elseif($valA < $valB){
        $result = -1;
    } else {
        $result = 0;
    }
    return $result;
}

usort($array, "customOrder");
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, i've already marked @piotr answer as the best but i'm guna test yours too..

Comment: I've tested your code here but it seems to output all of my array input... http://phpio.net/s/1lqf But don't worry i've got a working function now. Many thanks

Comment: it's only custom ordering function. Personally, the best answer is @RomanPerekhrest 's code.

Comment: Ahh i see thanks man. So why is [@RomanPerekhrest's](
http://phpio.net/s/1lql) code better than [@piotr's code](http://phpio.net/s/1lpr)? They both work great, i'm torn why which one is better..?

Answer (score 0):

Because your ordering array appears to be an exhaustive list of possible download values, you can just filter that static array by the downloads values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8Ug4e))

```
var_export(
    array_intersect(
        $new_order,
        array_column($downloads, 'type')
    )
);
```

If there may be values in the downloads array that are not represented in the ordering array, then the sample data in the question should be adjusted to better represent the application data.